# How can I let the user choose size of a shoe in the store?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am making a shoe store in wordpress using Woocommerce.

I just want to know if there is a way to let the user choose a shoe with a specific size.

For example I want something like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hFt5.jpg)

Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use product attributes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a [Variable Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) type and set a "size" [product attribute](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/#section-6).

This will then let your users choose from a list of options. You will probably need to add some code to change the select dropdown into buttons to match your screenshot.